# Weak* continuity of linear maps

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I consider a linear map $T\colon X^*\to Y^*$, where $X^*$ and $Y^*$ are duals of Banach spaces. I would like to know if I can deduce that $T$ is weak* continuous (I consider the weak* topologies on both $X^*$ and $Y^*$) if I know either of the following:

1. $T$ is weak* continuous when restricted to the unit ball of $X^*$;
2. for any integer $n$, $T$ is weak* continuous when restricted to the ball $B(0; n)$ in $X^*$.

In my case neither $X$ nor $Y$ is reflexive.

Comment: 1 and 2 are trivially equivalent from linearity of $T$.  The interesting part is whether they are equivalent to $T$ is w* continuous on all of $X^*$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. From the Krein Smulian theorem (use Google) you get that $T^*$ maps $Y$ into $X$.